# comparing strings in gdb command file for core dumps

Tags: string, gdb, coredump

I need to compare two strings,
One will be taken as am argument from the gdb command line interface
The other is stored in a variable
for a core dump

can anyone suggest a way to do so?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Without a running process your best bet would probably be the [Python GDB Extension](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Python-API.html).

Comment: I tried to do that, bt couldnt due to some constraints,

Is there no way other than using python?